# Android - startActivityForResult onActivityResult get ArrayList back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

This is how I send an ArrayList:

```
val extras = Bundle()

val i = Intent(context, GalleryShow::class.java)
i.putExtra("list", ArrayList(memes))
(context as Activity).startActivityForResult(i, 777)
```

and receive it in Activity B:

```
intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>
```

then after modifying it I set the intent that suppose to go back to Activity A:

```
private lateinit var finishIntent: Intent

finishIntent = Intent()

finishIntent.putExtra("list", ArrayList(modifiedMemes))
setResult(RESULT_OK, finishIntent)
```

and try to receive it in A:

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)

    if(requestCode == 777 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        if(data.hasExtra("list")) {
            val updatedMemes = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>
        }
    }
}
```

so I set it exactly the same way for sending and recieving from a to b but I get the error:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null
```

on

```
val updatedMemes = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>
```

What is wrong here? Does google actually care that android is a giant disfunctional pile of dog crap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from the wrong intent - you're using `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>`, referring to the `intent` property of your Activity and **not** the `data` Intent that you received from `onActivityResult()`:

```
val updatedMemes = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Memes>("list") as ArrayList<Memes>
```